# Magento 2 - Batch Update SKU in database to remove /

Tags: magento2

We have a problem that we can't use the Magento API to load products where the SKU has a / in it. To get around it I am looking at bulk updating all our SKU's to replace the / with a _

These are all the tables I can find that have an sku column, does anyone know if it would cause any issues if I ran the following?

```
Update `catalog_product_entity` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `catalog_product_option` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `catalog_product_option_type_value` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `inventory_reservation` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `inventory_source_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `quote_address_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `quote_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `sales_creditmemo_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `sales_invoice_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `sales_order_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
Update `sales_shipment_item` SET sku = Replace(sku,"/","_");
```

Or is there a better way to bulk update all the SKU's?

Cheers,
Tim